# Java - Method for batch processing text files is much slower then the same action individually the same amount of times

Tags: java, text, methods, batch-processing, text-classification

I wrote a method `processTrainDirectory` which is supposed to import and process all the text files from a given directory. Individually processing the files takes about the same time for each file (90ms), but when I use the method for batch importing a given directory, the time per file increases incrementally (from 90ms to over 4000ms after 300 files). The batch importing method is as follows:

```
public void processTrainDirectory(String folderPath, Category category) {
    File folder = new File(folderPath);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    if (listOfFiles != null) {
        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                processTrainText(file.getPath(), category);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(foo);
    }

}
```

As I said, the method `processTrainText` is called per text file in the directory. This method takes incrementally longer when used inside `processTrainDirectory`. The method `processTrainText` is as follows:

```
 public void processTrainText(String path, Category category){
    trainTextAmount++;
    Map<String, Integer> text = prepareText(path);
    update(text, category);

}
```

I called `processTrainText` 200 times on 200 different texts manual and the time that this took was 200 * 90ms. But when I have a directory of 200 files and use `processTrainDirectory` it takes 90-92-96-104....3897-3940-4002ms which is WAY longer.

The problem persists when I call `processTrainText` a second time; it does not reset. Do you have any idea why this is or what the cause it, and how I can solve it?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: somebody asked what other called methods did so here are all the used methods from my class `BayesianClassifier` all others are deleted for clarification, underneath you can find the class `Category`:

```
public class BayesianClassifier {
    private Map<String, Integer> vocabulary;
    private List<Category> categories;
    private int trainTextAmount;
    private int testTextAmount;
    private GUI gui;


    public Map<String, Integer> prepareText(String path) {
        String text = readText(path);
        String normalizedText = normalizeText(text);
        String[] tokenizedText = tokenizeText(normalizedText);
        return countText(tokenizedText);
    }

    public String readText(String path) {
        BufferedReader br;
        String result = "";
        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            result = sb.toString();
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return result;
    }


    public Map<String, Integer> countText(String[] words){
        Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i=0; i < words.length; i++){
            if (!result.containsKey(words[i])){
                result.put(words[i], 1);
            }
            else {
                result.put(words[i], result.get(words[i]) + 1);
            }
        }
          return result;
    }

    public void processTrainText(String path, Category category){
        trainTextAmount++;
        Map<String, Integer> text = prepareText(path);
        update(text, category);   
    }

    public void update(Map<String, Integer> text, Category category) {
        category.addText();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : text.entrySet()){
            if(!vocabulary.containsKey(entry.getKey())){
                vocabulary.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                category.updateFrequency(entry);
                category.updateProbability(entry);
                category.updatePrior();
            }

            else {
                vocabulary.put(entry.getKey(), vocabulary.get(entry.getKey()) + entry.getValue());
                category.updateFrequency(entry);
                category.updateProbability(entry);
                category.updatePrior();
            }

            for(Category cat : categories){
                if (!cat.equals(category)){
                    cat.addWord(entry.getKey());
                    cat.updatePrior();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void processTrainDirectory(String folderPath, Category category) {
        File folder = new File(folderPath);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        if (listOfFiles != null) {
            for (File file : listOfFiles) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    processTrainText(file.getPath(), category);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(foo);
        }

    }
```

This is my `Category` class (all the methods that are not needed are deleted for clarification:

```
public class Category {
    private String categoryName;
    private double prior;
    private Map<String, Integer> frequencies;
    private Map<String, Double> probabilities;
    private int textAmount;
    private BayesianClassifier bc;

    public Category(String categoryName, BayesianClassifier bc){
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.bc = bc;
        this.frequencies = new HashMap<>();
        this.probabilities = new HashMap<>();
        this.textAmount = 0;
        this.prior = 0.00;
    }

    public void addWord(String word){
        this.frequencies.put(word, 0);
        this.probabilities.put(word, 0.0);
    }

    public void updateFrequency(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry){
        if(!this.frequencies.containsKey(entry.getKey())){
            this.frequencies.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        else {
            this.frequencies.put(entry.getKey(), this.frequencies.get(entry.getKey()) + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public void updateProbability(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry){
        double chance = ((double) this.frequencies.get(entry.getKey()) + 1) / (sumFrequencies() + bc.getVocabulary().size());
        this.probabilities.put(entry.getKey(), chance);
    }

    public Integer sumFrequencies(){
        Integer sum = 0;
        for (Integer integer : this.frequencies.values()) {
            sum = sum + integer;
        }
        return sum;
    }  
}
```

Comment: mother in law's death ......???? Awesome :)

Comment: @TotalCare While funny, it's not really appropriate. That's probably why.

Comment: Did you profile the application?

Comment: "It does not reset" - what is supposed to reset? What are those `prepareText()` and `update()` methods doing? We can't help you without knowing that.

Comment: Most likely you are overloading your system and the work performed doesn't scale as you attempt to do more work at once.  I would work out what is it the optimum number of tasks to do at once is. It could be 1.

Comment: I meant profiling the application. So you know where the time is spent, instead of guessing, or asking on SO.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, I did, the most time is in `update` but the question I ask is, when i'm running `processTrainText` 200 times it takes 200*90ms and when I call the method `processTrainDirectory` with 200 files in it it takes 200*2000ms because the time per step is increasing on every execute when called by `processTrainDirectory`

Comment: @RealSkeptic i'm calling this method two times for two different directories so after the method `processTrainDirectory` ends the first time it begins again but the times between two `processTrainTexts` is still where it was from the first directory, so 4000ms, 4040ms etc.

Comment: There is still not enough information to go on. You should probably reduce this down to a [mcve]. The rule is: for any method you call which is not a standard library method, you should also include the code and variable declaration. You still haven't given `prepareText` and now you have added a lot more calls we can't possibly know the complexity of. Thus, reduce your code to an MCVE and post something we can run and analyze.

Comment: @RealSkeptic my Class is only 150 lines so I added the entire Class for you!

Comment: I give up. Yes, the `Category` class is also needed. And you should look at it and see if it calls any other classes, and include them, and so on. So please consider that [mcve].

Comment: @RealSkeptic I did what you asked for, changed my entire post!

Comment: @TotalCare And this was necessary as the culprit is hidden down in `Category`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the times per file are growing linearly and the total time quadratically. This means that with each file you're processing the data of all previous files. Indeed, you are:

`updateProbability` calls `sumFrequencies`, which runs through the entire `frequencies`, which grows with each file. That's the culprit. Simply create a field `int sumFrequencies` and update it in `updateFrequency.

As a further improvement, consider using Guava [Multiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html), which does the counting in a simpler and more efficient way (no autoboxing). After fixing your code, consider letting it be reviewed on [CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java); there are quite a few minor problems with it.

Comment: Hóóóly moly dude, you just made our program 2.300 times faster after 3 days of working on/with it. First it took 28 minutes to process 600 texts and now it takes 6 seconds in total. You are now officialy the main hero of two random students somewhere in the Netherlands.

Answer (score 0):

what is this method doing?

```
update(text, category);
```

If it is doing what may be a random call of me than this may be your bottleneck.
If you call it in a single way without additional context and it is updating some general data structure than yes it will always take the same time.
If it updates something that holds data from your past iterations than I am pretty sure it will take more and more time - check complexiy of update() method then and reduce your bottleneck.

Update:
Your method `updateProbability` is working on all the data you gathered so far when **you are calculating sum of frequencies** - thus taking more and more time the more files you process. This is your bottleneck.
There is no need of calculating it every time - just save it and update it every time something changes to minimize amount of calculation.

Comment: so if anybody feels to downvote this answer - fine. But at least the popup tells you to leave a comment to argue why.

Comment: @Stefan what popup is that? There is no obligation on anybody to leave a comment. I believe it's probably because your answer is not really an answer but a comment followed by a speculation. You should wait for more information before you answer.

Comment: @RealSkeptic if I downvote I get a notification to leave a comment - anyhow. I agree that this should be a comment you are right..